# Missing maven compile error link to source code in eclipse oxygen

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I installed eclipse oxygen and converted switched my build from ant to maven.
Everything works well except that compile errors don't show up as links to the source code.

I found a description and solution for IntelliJ in https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000527084-Link-from-Compilation-Failures-to-Source-Code
but it doesn't help in eclipse. Is there a solution for eclipse to get the links working?

Comment: Does eclipse provide a way of linking the failure to source code even?

Comment: Good question, that I don't know for maven builds, Error messages look like:  [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) on project CommTestScripts2: Compilation failure  [ERROR] /D:/git/CommTestScripts2/test/at/bachmann/se/commTest/UtilTest.java:[1849,34] ';' expected

Comment: That's a compilation error.  Fix it.

Comment: @duffymo He asked how to display this messages(errors) so that he has a link in the build console. So he doesn't has to fix this. it is an example.

Comment: I don't understand.  He has to fix compilation and linkage errors.

Comment: Hi @duffymo, I changed the because I wanted to get a compiler error. I just wanted to know how I get link in the error message to be able to jump to the mentioned source line, as usual in present IDEs.

Comment: IntelliJ lets me get right to the error for easy fixes.  I haven't used Eclipse since I learned about JetBrains 12 years ago.  Maybe you should think about a better IDE.

Comment: @duffymo thanks for the advise, we go with eclipse bacause we also built a customer tool on ontop of it.

Comment: That's a bad idea.  I'm sorry for your customers.